# How to build custom query in Spring boot for mongodb repository with $and and $or clause?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongorepository

How to build a custom query for mongodb(using mongodb template) for the following query in Spring boot?

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find(
   {$or:[
    {$and:[{"name":"xyz"},{"address:"1234"}]},
    {$and:[{"name":"abc"},{"address":"001"}]},
    {..}
    {..so on..}
    ]})
```

Can we use Criteria Query to query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your query in this way:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.orOperator( 
    Criteria.where("name").is("xyz").and("address").is("1234"),
    Criteria.where("name").is("abc").and("address").is("001"),
    Criteria.where(...),
    Criteria.where(...)
);
Query query = new Query(criteria);
mongoTemplate.find(query, YourClass.class, "CollectionName");
```

If the number of criteria that you have to use is not fixed, you can populate a list of `Criteria` and pass it to the `orOperator` function:

```
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();
for (...) {
    //populate list
    criterias.add(Criteria.where(...).is(...).and(...).is(...);
}
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.orOperator(criterias);
```

Comment: Please view the edited query

Comment: @JavaProgrammer did this work for you?